# Overwrite page attributes with fluid in TYPO3 V9

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I need to overwrite page attributes (e.g. canonical links) with fluid.

The concept of just adding it does not work, because afterwards there would be two canonical links:

```
<n:headerData>
   <link rel="canonical" href="{newsItem.link}">
</n:headerData>
```

How can I get the page data from TYPO3 to overwrite the attribute?

Comment: please add the TYPO3 version of your installation.

Comment: It's TYPO3 v9.5 @BerndWilkeπφ

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can find, there is no option to modify the `canonical`tag.

[here](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Feature-20051-SupportTheCanonicalTag.html) you can find the hint that only one extension can be active to generate the `canonical` tag.

and [here](https://www.typo3-n%C3%BCrnberg.de/typo/konfiguration/page-header-tags/) (german) you find the only solution to deactivate `ext:seo` to build an own `canonical` tag.